Model is shaking in gazebo
Using "view contacts"in gazebo,I found the model was shaking.How can I modify my urdf file efficiently to keep the model stay still?


Your problem is likely to be in gazebo. Your model must have so much mass that it exerts incredible high impluses on any collision it experiences, i.e. collisions with hard surfaces. This plus an unfortunate collision mesh that points its surface normals in different directions can create bouncy behavior.
You may have multiple ways of solving this.

Make your model completely static that should make your model from a physics perspective immovable.
Tweak your physics. Lower your step size, try a different physics engine that plays nicer with your high mass.
Reduce hardness of your collision elements

You are talking about changing your urdf, so I assume you are using an sdf parser for gazebo.
Some fields may get translated properly, but if there is no equivalent, remember you can reference blocks to gazebo with a name tag inside your urdf:
<gazebo reference="your_name">

PS: In any way you do better in allowing limited contacts for your collision elements. Benefits the behavior you are describing, but also overall performance.

Thank you for your advice!I will adopt theses ways to modify my model.

Let me know if and what works for you!

thank you for your response!I was busy to do my undergraduate graduation project this time！sorry for replying you so late！previously,i tried to modify the mass and moment of inertia without any effective methods,just modified the number and observed how the model changed.The physics label such as friction has been tried without any changes.Maybe I should use another physics engine?
